# Excel VBA - Making points invisible removes markers

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I'm having a problem to making some points of my series (making them invisible). In the image below, you can see that it goes well until I make the point invisible. The marker's legend get all confused and set the legend to the XValues, in this case "1","2", and so on.

Is it possible to make a point invisible but keeping the original marker legend?

[image: Points removed as well the markers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest to substitute the "invisible" points' values with `CVErr(xlErrNA)`? That way the line will still be drawn, but these points will be "ignored".
Or do you need to mantain those values?

Comment: Going with this solution by now. It would be great make it desappear, but thanks a lot. It is better than it was!